# Android EditBox responses slow when entering data

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, mobile

I am testing my android application on Galaxy S3. I have a form having views like Edit Box, radios, drop down..  When I edit any EditText the keyboard responses slow. When I run the form separately it performs fine.

Here is logs of LogCat

```
07-26 12:39:46.925: D/SensorManager(3165): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b(a+e8
07-26 12:39:46.925: I/SensorManager(3165): Set min delay = 200000
07-26 12:39:46.925: I/SensorManager(3165): Before sending... delay = 200000
07-26 12:39:46.925: D/Sensors(3165): Remain listener = android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@419e6320
07-26 12:39:46.925: I/Sensors(3165): sendDelay --- 200000000
07-26 12:39:46.955: D/SensorManager(3165): JNI - sendDelay
07-26 12:39:46.985: D/SensorManager(3165): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= MPU-6050 Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))b..,8
07-26 12:39:47.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3165): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-26 12:39:47.045: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3165): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-26 12:39:47.045: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3165): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-26 12:39:48.446: D/dalvikvm(3165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1974K, 17% free 17467K/20999K, paused 3ms+56ms, total 175ms
07-26 12:39:50.428: D/dalvikvm(3165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2035K, 17% free 17440K/20999K, paused 3ms+54ms, total 174ms
07-26 12:39:52.590: D/dalvikvm(3165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2003K, 17% free 17442K/20999K, paused 15ms+32ms, total 166ms
07-26 12:39:55.843: D/dalvikvm(3165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1998K, 17% free 17455K/20999K, paused 13ms+48ms, total 181ms
```

Comment: My Code is too larger then limit it can not b added here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabActivity is deprecated in android jelly bean that is cause of slowness of keyboard. so I have removed it works fine than.